# WinSCP Commandline Private key

Tags: command-line, ssh, winscp, private-key

What I am trying to so is: Open a WInSCP-Session using a private key instead of a password.

The simple Password-Approach works:

```
 WinSCP.exe root:password@example.com
```

But the next step, using the key, does not work. Just to be clear. I mean this key:
[image]

I tried:

```
 WinSCP.exe root@example.com /privatekey "path/to/private_key.ppk"
```

But WinSCP ignores the parameter and asks for the password. So, what did I forget?

Comment: Did you lock your private key with a password?

Comment: `open scp://root@example.com:2222/ -privatekey=private_key.ppk` try this?

Comment: You are missing a `=` after the `/privatekey`. It should be `/privatekey="path/to/private_key.ppk"`. See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`winscp.exe username@127.0.0.1 /privatekey=x:\mykeys\mykeys.ppk` works for me, but this will still prompt for the "Private Key Passphrase".

Two options you can do:

- Let the private key unsecured without passphrase (not recommended)
- Use Pageant (included in WinSCP installation, or available from [PuTTY download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)). Pageant can "save" your private key passphrase and make it resident (for the session), and WinSCP can interact with Pageant and allow you to use your encrypted private key.

Hope this helps.
PS: You don't need to put the password anymore (as per to your question root:password) if you got the correct private key

Comment: Thanks, this way it works! And the password was just a copy-paste error, I removed it.

Comment: Worth noting, that once you load your private key to Pageant, you do not need to use the `/privatekey=` command-line argument anymore. The Pageant holds whole decrypted key in the memory, not only the passphrase (actually, it does not save the passphrase at all).